# Create List from Another List in MVC

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one list populated from Database with properties code_type , description , min_value, max_value, id etc

I want to create another lists  from list 1 with filter condition value of code_type with only three properties 
i.e description , min_value, & max value (code_type is not required). This revised list will be used for to bind View in MVC 
\Kindly help for the same

Below is my code for the same. If **code ="04"** Then populate list for caste & so on. Can I Use Linq for the same?

```
public class MyPrefernce
{
   public string memberid { get; set; }
   public string code { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
   public long? min_value { get; set; }
   public long? max_value { get; set; }
   public long? sysid { get; set; }
   public string isChecked { get; set; }
   public List<Caste> lcaste;



   public List<MyPrefernce> getPrefence(long sysmemberid, string memberid)
   {
      List<MyPrefernce> lstObj = new List<MyPrefernce>();
      string strQuery = "proc_Get_Member_Preference";
      Connection cobj = new Connection();
      string strConnection = cobj.getConnectionString();
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nSysMemberId", sysmemberid);
      SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      ada.Fill(ds);
      if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
          {
            MyPrefernce obj = new MyPrefernce();
            obj.code = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["code"].ToString();
            obj.isChecked = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["isChecked"].ToString();
            obj.min_value = Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["min_value"]);
            obj.max_value = Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["max_value"]);
            obj.sysid = sysid;
            obj.memberid = memberid;
            lstObj.Add(obj);
           }
         }
       return lstObj;
        }
    }

public class Caste
{
   public int sysId { get; set; }
   public string decription { get; set; }
   public string? isChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new class, defining the fields you need, and use auto-mapper to map the the fields between classes.